# Laravel Livewire wire:submit.prevent not working as intended

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple form:

```xml
<form class="w-full" wire:submit.prevent="postComment">
     <textarea 
         type="text" 
         name="comment" 
         id="comment"
         wire:model.defer="newCommentState.body" 
         class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" 
         placeholder="Leave a comment!">
    </textarea>
    <button 
        type="submit" 
        class="justify-items-start btn rounded-full m-3">
        Comment
    </button>
</form>
@error('newCommentState.body')
    <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-500">{{ $message }}</p>
@enderror
```

and the Livewire Component:

```php
public $newCommentState = [
    'body' => ''
];

public function postComment()
{
   dd($this->newCommentState);
}
```

All the above code is running on Livewire 2x and alpine 3x, and the @livewire scripts are included in the \layout\app.blade.php.

but for some reason when I click the submit button it reloads the page and appends a "?comment=" to the url.

I assumed the problem was the views being cashed so I ran `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan optimize:clear`, yet that did not help. I also cleared my browser cache thinking that it would help but had no luck.

Can someone please enlighten on a solution to this problem, or point out what I might be doing wrong.

`Thanks In Advance`

Comment: What if you don't use `dd()`? Does the same behavior occurs when using `dump()` ? The difference between the 2 is that `dd` dumps the variable and stops execution, `dump` doesn't stop execution.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the livewire component because the form isn't really reaching the dd(); with or without it I still get the same reaction from the form.

Comment: What about changing the textarea for an `<input type="text">` ? Also, I just noticed the  `type="text"` attribute. That's not valid in a `<textarea>`. You could also try closing the textarea. `<textarea></textarea>` to make sure the line break isn't changing the value in any way.

Comment: I tried changing the textarea to input:text but still no luck. Also removed the type text from the textarea but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: having the same issue. were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: No, Not yet, but I opened a discussion on the livewire discussion forum on GitHub, hopefully they'll have a solution: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/4640

Answer (score 1):

Following the [troubleshooting docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#root-element-issues), there should be a **root element issues**.

Livewire requires that there be only one HTML element at the root of a components blade view, that's not your case, you have a Form and a P.

The solution is to ensure that you only have one root HTML element, such as a `<div>`. If you have multiple elements, then wrap everything in a  or another element that suits your layout.

Your code should be like this:

```html
<div>
<form class="w-full" wire:submit.prevent="postComment">
     <textarea 
         type="text" 
         name="comment" 
         id="comment"
         wire:model.defer="newCommentState.body" 
         class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full" 
         placeholder="Leave a comment!">
    </textarea>
    <button 
        type="submit" 
        class="justify-items-start btn rounded-full m-3">
        Comment
    </button>
</form>
@error('newCommentState.body')
    <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-500">{{ $message }}</p>
@enderror
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to put `@livewireScripts` at the end before closing body tag

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 create live wire component
Step 2 create a route ; laravel 8 is defined as below
Route::get('someroute' , App\Http\Livewire\LiveWireComponentName::class);

Step 3 Livewire component are in 2 parts, class, and view file
Step 4 In layouts/app.blade.php create a new file called livewire.blade.php
Step 5 Define the following layout, and. make sure to include the component

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
   @livewire('componentname')  ----> This is most important
   @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

Step 6 Once the layout is defined, create the submit method, and form
Step 7 Go to config/livewire.php, and inside the layout change the layout to "layouts.livewire"

Step 8 Done